# Washing machine drain into 4" cast waste stack

Tags: plumbing

[image]Can I drain my washing machine into a 4" diameter cast iron stack?
I want to take my washing machine out of the basement and reinstall it in kitchen above.
I would like to drill into the stack to take  1 1/2" pvc drain pipe. The washer drain is 8 feet from the stack. It's currently using trap, and back up valve.

Comment: Are you more worried about how to drill into a cast iron stack, or whether this arrangement would be permissible by your local building regulations?

Comment: thank you for reply. No just like to know if you think it will work when toilet upstairs is flushed it  has two sinks toilet and  shower .  Old home and mostly cast all other drains are vented into stack above waste I think.Just have no place to run drain otherwise than stack in basement thank you again welcome your advice Don

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have more difficulty drilling into the cast iron stack, than routing a new pipe. Follow the route of the stack down with your 2 1/2 pipe, and then feed it into your waste water system, using the correct fitting

Comment: you might have something there. I could run 1 1/2 pvc from washer down to waste pipe Y with proper grade and back up valve  pack it with oakum and cement it will need couple more length,s pvc pipe Will upload pix of area to site .Than you  for your input  Do (have great day)

Comment: This is pix of upstairs sink (kitchen) will leave for now till washing machine is hooked.There is a Y at end of waste stack to sewer .like you suggested will run pipe into unused section of Y